# Last image in ListView won't show up until I scroll down (randomly)

Tags: listview, react-native

I'm using React Native's `<ListView>` to display images 3 images per row, just like what Instagram does. However, the last image on last row, which is initially shown half due to screen height limit, sometimes can't show up until I scroll down.

[image: Image revealed after scroll only]

Related codes:

```
export const thumbnails = {
    'cat1': require('./images/cat1.png'),
    'cat2': require('./images/cat2.png'),
    'cat3': require('./images/cat3.png'),
    'cat4': require('./images/cat4.png'),
    'cat5': require('./images/cat5.png'),
    'cat6': require('./images/cat6.png'),
    'cat7': require('./images/cat7.png'),
    'cat8': require('./images/cat8.png'),
    'cat9': require('./images/cat9.png'),
    'cat10': require('./images/cat10.png'),
    'cat11': require('./images/cat11.png'),
    'cat12': require('./images/cat12.png'),
};

export default class App extends React.Component {
  // For List View
  constructor() {
    super();
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3', 'cat4', 'cat5', 'cat6', 'cat7', 'cat8', 'cat9', 'cat10', 'cat11', 'cat12', ]),
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1}}>
            <ScrollableTabView 
      renderTabBar={() => <CustomTabBar />}> 
                <ListView tabLabel="tab1" contentContainerStyle={{flexDirection: 'row', flexWrap: 'wrap', alignItems: 'flex-start',}}
style={{flex:1}} dataSource={this.state.dataSource} renderRow={(rowData) => <Image resizeMode="contain" style={{width: width / 3, height: width / 3}} source={thumbnails[rowData]} />} />
                <View tabLabel="tab2" style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', height: 300}}>
                    <Text style={{color: '#000'}}>Page 2 here</Text>
                </View>
                <View tabLabel="tab3" style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', height: 300}}>
                    <Text style={{color: '#000'}}>Page 3 here</Text>
                </View>
                <View tabLabel="tab4" style={{alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', height: 300}}>
                    <Text style={{color: '#000'}}>Page 4 here</Text>
                </View>
            </ScrollableTabView> 
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

How can I fix this issue? the cat images are less than 20KB each and it's running on iPhone 7 Plus via Expo App, thus memory shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: There are many props you can put on your ListView to choose the initial render size, for example `initialListSize` or `pageSize`

Comment: Can you give some examples of using these 2 props? Since the App is going to support multiple screen sizes, do I need different values for different sizes?